# Relational algebra without using count

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

This is a question from my database class's practice midterm. Say I have the following relational schema:

`WorkList(EMP#, WorkType#, Season) EMP#`, `WorkType#` and `Season` combine to form the primary key

```
(121, 1, Winter)
(121, 2, Winter)
(114, 1, Spring)
(114, 2, Spring)
(114, 2, Fall)
```

should return tuples

```
(114)
```

What is the relational algebraic expression I can use to return the workers who have at some point only worked on one `WorkType#` in a season? We can only use union, set minus, cartesian product, natural join, select, project, rename and intersection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without grouping operators, we have to do a little bit of a roundabout method to get the result needed:

1. Take the Cartesian product of the table with itself (I'll now refer to the attributes as `EMP1`, `EMP2`, `Worktype1`, etc. Note for "proper" relational algebra, you would have to rename these attributes prior to the Cartesian product).
2. Select tuples with `EMP1 = EMP2`, `Season1 = Season2`, `WorkType1 != WorkType2`. Note some definitions of relational algebra do not allow `!=` in a predicate. It's still possible without it, but more workarounds would be needed. I'll assume I can use it.
3. Project and rename `EMP1, WorkType1, Season1` to your original attribute names.  You now have a relation containing instances where a worker has worked on more than one work type in a season.
4. Take the set difference of your original table with the one obtained in Step 3. This relation only has instances where a worker only worked on one work type in a season.
5. Project the `EMP#` attribute.